# jquery ajax method is not Loading Text File

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am learning jquery ajax() from w3c school
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

I have one html file , 1 text file("demo_test.txt") in same folder. on button click . html should load  text file :

here is code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url:"demo_test.txt",success:function(result){
      $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Text file only have data "this is text file".

But some How it is not working . Other similar post dont have this scenario.. is there any problem placing text file physically ? please suggest

Comment: try add dataType: "text", (after url:"demo_test.txt", )

Comment: You are not redirecting. You are just loading the contents of demo_test.txt and displaying it.

Comment: i edited the subject and content

Comment: your code is 100%, correct , just verify the location of demo_test.txt file, I tried myself it worked. Which browser are you using

Answer (score 1):

I finally seems to Get it working . Here is working Script

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url:"http://localhost/demo_test.txt",success:function(result){
      $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
  });
```

Workaround : put the html file and text file on local server (IIS) New Site .

Answer (score 0):

You’re displaying the txt file in the browser but when you click on button at the time page was postback then your text file content not displayed on the page so you need to just restrict to postback the page.
So you just change javascript as below

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            $.ajax({ url: "demo_test.txt",
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#div1").html(result);
                },
                error: function (abc) {
                    alert(abc.statusText);
                },
                cache:false
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Still not working , i replaced with your script..i debug with firebug in fiefox .. it is point to return false

Comment: Please change the script which was updated in answer and check. If you get “No Found” then your txt file is unable to find.

Comment: my Text file is "demo_test.txt" . and it is in the same folder in which html file is .i also tried to change url:"demo_test.txt" to url:"./demo_test.txt"...but still no luck ... i think it is not taking  text file from the path ..

Comment: I tried above script and it is working.do you replaced it and you get any alert ?

Comment: it gives the followig error now :[Exception... "Access to restricted URI denied"  code: "1012" nsresult: "0x805303f4 (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI)"  location: "<unknown>"] .. if it means text file not found .. how to set it ??

Comment: This error reason is your request accessed cross domain but your txt file is in local so not possible this error in your case. Can you show me your project structure?

Comment: actually this is not project . i am just learning from tutorial . i have only one local folder in which these are 2 physical file . "my_html" Html page and "demo_test.txt" text file

Comment: I have able to generate your required output.so please give me your email id so I can send you test page.

Comment: i didnot recieve the mail since yesterday .. ?? any more suggestion ?