# How to use jsonop in jquery ajax when loading a text file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

this Question is in relation to my previous question which is still unanswered:

[jquery ajax method is not Loading Text File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833440/jquery-ajax-method-is-not-loading-text-file/21833861?noredirect=1#comment33049611_21833861)

I am trying to load Textfile with in html page using jquery ajax method ,html and text are hosted on localserver..How should i call "jsonp" method with callback in this case ?

My Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
         $.ajax({
     url:"http://localhost/demo_test.txt",
     dataType: 'jsonp', 
     success:function(){

         alert("Success");
     },
     error:function(){
         alert("Error");
     },
});
           return false;
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Please suggest . I am getting cross domain error every time

Comment: You said your html and txt are hosted on the same localserver, then there's no need to use jsonp, for they are in the same domain. Well, maybe you just mean they are on the same computer without a http server?

Answer (score 0):

JQuery ajax function may have a cross-domain request, which is jsonp, but you can't use it like this!

the server-side that responding a jsonp request is actually a javascript function, for example:

js file:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
       url: 'http://xxx.xxx.com/yoururl',
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       success: function(data) {
           console.log(data)
       }
});
```

server-side(php for example)

```
<?php
    $fn = $_GET['callback'];//get the jquery callback parameter
    $data = array("name"=>"name1", "age"=>12); //make a data object to pass it as a parameter!
    echo $fn . "(" . json-encode($data) . ");"; // the response actually generate a javascript function!
?>
```

In your code, the txt file is not a valid jsonp response!

Comment: so How to load text file with jquery ajax  ? I just want to implement a example code from tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_ajax but it is not working since long

Comment: Ok , I started getting data of text file , but the Button (<button>Get External Content</button> )of html page still left in Text file . How to remove it

Answer (score 0):

OK . i finally got it working :
Here is Working Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url:"http://localhost/demo_test.txt",success:function(result){
      $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>

</script>
</head>
```